# Algorithm to find min & max value of equation from an array

Tags: algorithm, excel, vba

I have an array of 8 int, 4 positive and 4 negative.

```
X [10,-2,30,-4,5,-20,8,-9]
```

Now, let

```
Evaluated = a-b+c-d+e-f+g-h
```

where a,b..h are unique values taken from X.
I need to ensure that

Case 1. Evaluated = closest to zero.
Case 2. List out the 5 greatest possibility by solving Evaluated.
        I can find the maximum value by sorting the array and assigning the max values to a,c,e and g, and the minimum values b,d,f and h. but how to find the next 4 values?

There are 8! ways of solving this equation right?

What would be the best way of determining this solution?

Comment: In a comment to an answer you wrote  “The actual aim is to identify pairs that provide the least/cancel out from the 8 numbers. Hence giving the lowest total to the equation.”  The idea of cancellation suggests you want the absolute value of the total to be small, rather than the algebraic value.  If so, please edit question to match.

Comment: It sounds like you actually want to select pairs such that abs(a+b) + abs(c+d) + abs(e+f) + abs(g+h) is minimized.

Answer (score 5):

Ensure that negative values get positive sign and positive values get negative sign. You will be getting smallest possible value. You don't even need to sort.

One simple way of doing is this...

```
Loop Each Element of X

    if X[i] > 0 Then X[i] = -1 * X[i]

End Loop

Add all elements of X (yes just don't think about subtracting, just add)
```

The result sum is the smallest possible value.

Answer (score 1):

Just choose a, c, e, g as the four smallest and the rest as the largest values.

Function [`Small`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/small-function-HP010342904.aspx) in Excel might help you.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, you have an array of eight numbers. You want to choose four of the numbers to add, and four to subtract in order to get the smallest possible result. I would proceed as follows:

1. **Sort** the array from smallest to largest. [This article](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/SortingArrays.aspx) describes two ways to do this. In your example, the sorted array would have [-20, -9, -4, -2, 5, 8, 10, 30].
2. **Add** The first four values in the array.
3. **Subtract** The last four values.

This will give you the smallest result possible by adding four values and subtracting the remaining values in the array of eight.

Comment: The actual aim is to identify pairs that provide the least/cancel out from the 8 numbers. Hence giving the lowest total to the equation.

How would one find the maximum? I used something similar to what @ZiyaoWei posted. Select a,c,e,g as the maximum values and substitute the rest.

Comment: If you're looking for the pairs with least absolute value, then sort the array as here, and match largest to smallest, second largest to second smallest, and so on.